# Why do I get +1 hour when calculating time difference in javascript?

Tags: javascript, time

I trying to create a very simple time difference calculation. Just "endtime - starttime". I'm getting +1 hour though. I suspect it has with my timezone to do, since I'm GMT+1.

Regardless, that should not affect the difference, since both start and end times are in the same timezone.

Check my running example-code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kaze72/Rm3f3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tid1 =  (new Date).getTime();

    $("#tid").click(function() {
        var nu = (new Date).getTime();
        var diff = new Date(nu - tid1);
        console.log(diff.getUTCHours() + ":" +
                diff.getUTCMinutes() + ":" +
               diff.getUTCSeconds());  
        console.log(diff.toLocaleTimeString());
    });
})
```

Comment: Consider using `Date.now()` instead of `(new Date()).getTime()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must understand what `Date` object represent and how it stores dates. Basically each `Date` is a thin wrapper around the number of milliseconds since 1970 (so called *epoch time*). By subtracting one date from another you don't get a date: you just get the number of milliseconds between the two.

That being said this line doesn't have much sense:

```
var diff = new Date(nu - tid1);
```

What you really need is:

```
var diffMillis = nu - tid1;
```

...and then simply extract seconds, minutes, etc.:

```
var seconds = Math.floor(diffMillis / 1000);
var secondsPart = seconds % 60;
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
var minutesPart = minutes % 60;
var hoursPart = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
//...
console.log(hoursPart + ":" + minutesPart + ":" + secondsPart);
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJZ45/).