# HTML5 video get currentTime not working with media events javascript addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

Im trying to show the current duration (print currenttime live) when the video is playing.

I did read Kurt Van den Branden answer on [Detect if HTML5 Video element is playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599076/detect-if-html5-video-element-is-playing) but to no avail

i eventually want to carry the currenttime value to a php variable $currenttime
below is my current code

```
<html> 
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Html5 media events</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body >
<div id="output"></div>
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
    <source src="http://action.news/videos/Britney%20Spears%20-%20Overprotected%20(2009)%20Full%20HD%201080p_60%20fps.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
    var media = document.getElementById('myVideo');

    // Playing event
    var isPlaying = function(e) {
    #$("#output").html("Playing event triggered");

    };

      // durationchange
    var isdurationchange = function(e) {
        $("#output").html(vid.currentTime);


    };

    media.addEventListener("playing", isPlaying, false);   
    media.addEventListener("durationchange", isdurationchange, true);    
</script>   
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You define `media` but then use `vid.currentTime`...?

Comment: that was from w3 schools

Comment: i need to pass it to html ..  document.write("<a href=/time.htm?currentTime='.media.addEventListener("timeupdate", isdurationchange, true).'>link</a>;);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to carry it like this , the pros will help you with syntax

```
 document.write("<a href=/time.htm?currentTime='.media.addEventListener("timeupdate", isdurationchange, true).'>link</a>;);
```

Comment: thanks thats what i pretty much want but it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

listen event `timeupdate` instead of `durationchange`
(also correct your typo error as @Jeto mentions in comment)

```js
var media = document.getElementById('myVideo');

    // Playing event
    var isPlaying = function(e) {
    $("#output").html("Playing event triggered");

    };

      // durationchange
    var isdurationchange = function(e) {
        $("#output").html(media.currentTime);
    };

    media.addEventListener("playing", isPlaying, false);   
 //   media.addEventListener("durationchange", isdurationchange, true);   
 
  media.addEventListener("timeupdate", isdurationchange, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
    <source src="http://fiber.westnet.ca:81/videos/Britney%20Spears%20-%20Overprotected.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: thanks is possible to transfer the current time to a php variiable?

Comment: and instead of milisecond time display the format from the video which is H:M:S i searched w3schools to no avial

Comment: i tried to carry it to a url <a href=<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>&ft><div id="output"></div></a> but no luck

Comment: thansk for your help, if my filename has ?& etc in it  how do i access it via apache? i tried rewrite htaccess to no avial

Comment: scraaappy is the answer i am new to this what do i do to reward him/you

Comment: Hello Nance, welcome to SO. If the answer brings you a solution and you think it's the best you have received, accept it. If it's just helpfull, upvote (contrary, if it's out of topic or false, downvote). If others question come on the same topic, update your own question without modifying the original one (add a paragraph, with a title like "edit" or "updated"), or post another question (before posting, be sure to check that the question has not already been asked on SO, otherwise, it will be downvoted)

Comment: For example, see here to format your output:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816872/how-can-i-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format-using-javascript
or here to send variable from javascript to php
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php
Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: still not working i need to pass the current time to a url a href=file.htm?currentime=currenttime