# JavaScript HoursBetween function

Tags: javascript, html

I need to find the difference, in hours, between two values(t1 and t2)
t1(Now) code:

```
<td><!--tc:minutes--></td>
```

t2(then) code:

```
<td><!--tc:time.cost--></td>
```

For example t1 is 1:11 (1 hours, 11 minutes)  and t2 is 1:05 (1 hours, 5 minutes)

How can I get the remaining time? 0:06 (0 hours, 6 minutes)? I think I need JavaScript function like HoursBetween in Delphi..

Comment: After you get the remaining time, where do you want to put it? Into a new `<td>`? Also do you want to do it server-side or client-side, and if server-side, what language are you using?

Comment: You can't do it with straight HTML.  You'll need some JavaScript at the least.

Comment: you can't do that with HTML, use server or cliend side language like php or javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13894670/1848929

Comment: javascript `Date()`https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// using Date objects
var start = Date.now();

// the event to time goes here:
doSomethingForALongTime();
var end = Date.now();
var elapsed = end - start; // elapsed time in milliseconds
// using built-in methods
var start = new Date();

// the event to time goes here:
doSomethingForALongTime();
var end = new Date();
var elapsed = end.getTime() - start.getTime(); // elapsed time in milliseconds
// to test a function and get back its return
function printElapsedTime(fTest) {
  var nStartTime = Date.now(),
      vReturn = fTest(),
      nEndTime = Date.now();

  console.log('Elapsed time: ' + String(nEndTime - nStartTime) + ' milliseconds');
  return vReturn;
}

yourFunctionReturn = printElapsedTime(yourFunction);
```