# How to calculate time spent on each state in ui-router (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Want to calculate time spent on each state separately in AngularJS routing. I'm using ui-router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get is using the time difference between previous route change and current route change... hook into `$stateChangeSuccess` event onto `$rootScope`,

the code would similar to below ( add it in your root-controller // app level controller)

```
     var timeStart;

     $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(current, prev){
            if(angular.isUndefined(timeStart)){
                 $log.info('this is the first route')
            } else {
                 var timeSpent = moment().diff(timeStart).format('mm:ss');
                 $log.info(`total time spent ${timeSpent} route ${prev.name}`);
                 timeStart = moment();
            }
     })
```

** EDIT **

it is using `momentjs`, you can use any date library for date manipulation/getting time difference, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894632/get-time-difference-between-two-dates-in-seconds) on how to do it

Comment: good answer, but you are using `momentjs` functionality here and PO hasn't asked the solution with `momentjs`. You should've mentioned in the answer here. +1 for the solution although. It adds something good to the post.

Comment: @entre, is there any solution without using momentjs

Comment: please go thru the link in edit, to find out how to do date manipulation using core javascript date object