# Countdown gets stuck at 01:00

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a countdown in jQuery but I have an issue. When the count reaches `01:00` it gets stuck instead of continuing on to `00:59` with minute of 0.

```
var start = $('#start');
var countMinutes = 2;

var timer;
start.on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  new Timer(function(val, countMinutes) {
    timerMsg = (countMinutes >= 10 ? countMinutes : '0' + countMinutes) + ':' + (val >= 10 ? val : '0' + val);
    time.text(timerMsg);
  });
});

function Timer(callback, val, m) {
  val = val || 59;
  m = countMinutes;
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    callback(val, m);
    if (val-- <= 0) {
      m -= 1;
      if (m < 1 && val <= 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      countMinutes = 0;
      val += 60;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

my html.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="timer"><span id="time">10:00</span></h1>
<a href="#" id="start">Start</a>
```

Comment: `if(m < 1 && val <= 0) {` if `m` is minutes what will happen?

Comment: FYI: setInterval is NOT accurate.

Comment: why is setInterval not accurate?

Comment: @DanielA.White the counter stops.

Comment: You'll get more accurate results using a Date object. [Get time difference between two dates in seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13894632/669576).

Comment: @EmudRon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985670/will-setinterval-drift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if (m < 1 && val <= 0) {
```

to

```
if (m < 0 && val <= 0) {
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
var countMinutes = 2;
var timer;

$('#start').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  new Timer(function(val, countMinutes) {
    timerMsg = (countMinutes >= 10 ? countMinutes : '0' + countMinutes) + ':' + (val >= 10 ? val : '0' + val);
    $('#time').text(timerMsg);
  });
});

function Timer(callback, val, m) {
  val = val || 59;
  m = countMinutes;
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    callback(val, m);
    if(val-- <= 0) {
      m -= 1;
      if(m < 0 && val <= 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      countMinutes = 0;
      val += 60;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="timer">
  
<span id="time">10:00</span></h1>

<a href="#" id="start">Start</a>
```

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to explain what you changed, and why. Just copy/pasting code isn't really teaching anyone anything :-)

Comment: you're right, as the code is working i didn't wanted to add more comments then the snippet, the problem with this code is that we can't understand the meaning of each variable by just reading it

Comment: when you enter the Timer function, val =59 or its actual value and m= countMinutes as a global variable, the callback function sets the text to be displayed every second seted by the setInterval then you have the if then else that just evalute if the timer has arrived to 0 or not but i don't understand the last two lines countMinutes = 0; and val +=60