# Calculate the difference in seconds between two epoch timestamps in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, difference, epoch

I'm trying to calculate the difference (in seconds) between two EPOCH timestamps using Javascript.

I have two timestamps:

```
START: 1565628094441
END: 1565714527812
```

Both timestamps were obtained using:

```
var time = new Date().getTime().toString();
```

I would like to determine the difference between both timestamps in seconds. I understand that Javascript returns epoch in milliseconds but I still haven't been able to find a way to convert them to seconds properly.

Here is what I've tried:

```
var differenceSec = (END- START)/1000;
// This gives us 86433.371 Seconds (~1440 minutes).
```

Using Epoch Converter (https://www.epochconverter.com/#tools) I know that the true difference should be around 30 seconds. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing was passed in when creating the dates... in order to get the current time:

var time = new Date().getTime().toString();

Comment: javascript is right, not some random website. i can tell by looking that those are more than 30 seconds apart.

Comment: There are 86400 seconds in a day. So I think epoch is dropping the day difference and just telling you the 30 seconds part

Comment: there is a day difference, START is aug 12, and END is aug 13

Comment: I've also done some testing using the toString method on the Date object. e.g. new Date(1565628094441).toString() and it matches the results of Epoch Converter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894632/get-time-difference-between-two-dates-in-seconds already answered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get time difference between two dates in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894632/get-time-difference-between-two-dates-in-seconds)

Comment: how do you `know that the true difference should be around 30 seconds.`?

Comment: I've made an error - the two dates were generated a day apart... therefor the calculation is correct as pointed out by @depperm

Answer (score 5):

There are `24 * 60 * 60 = 86400` seconds in a day. Your figure of `86433.371 - 1 day = 33.371` seconds. So if Epoch Converter is not counting days, you have your answer

Comment: I'm fairly certain the OP just missed the day, epoch converter is probably not doing anything wrong